# check validity of a subset of values between dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm looking to compare a list of `x` dictionaries (`actual`) against a list of `y` dictionaries (`expected`), where x > y. To ensure that the `expected` list exists exactly how it should in the `actual` list, except for the values of certain keys. These ignorable keys are known beforehand.

So I know that I could iterate over the `expected` list and check to see if each element in the `expected` list exists in the `actual` list. However, there are certain keys in the `actual` list whose existence I care about, but not value. I want to be able to do this without having to change either lists.

For example, here I care that the key `person` exists in the `actual` dictionaries - but I do not care about it's value. While I do care about the key and value for `time` and `place` exactly how it exists in `expected`. Currently I am doing the following:

```py
ignore_val = ['person']

expected = [{'time': '12:34:22', 'place': 'LA', 'person': 'Mike'}, {'time': '11:45:15', 'place': 'SF', 'person': 'Emily'}] 

actual = [{'time': '12:34:22', 'place': 'LA', 'person': 'Mike'}, {'time': '11:45:15', 'place': 'SF', 'person': 'Emily'}, {'time': '21:19:57', 'place': 'LA', 'person': 'Leo'}, {'time': '15:43:11', 'place': 'LA', 'person': 'Marge'}] 

for exp in expected:
    if exp.items() not in [act.items() for act in actual]:
        return False
return True
```

However, how would I go about including the existence of the `person` key while simultaneously excluding the existence of it's value without having to create a new data structure with only the "items" I care about? What is the most pythonic way to do this?

EDIT:

Is there a better way than this:

```
keys = [act.keys() for act in actual]
vals = [{k:v for k, v in act.items() if k not in ignore_val} for act in actual]

for exp in expected:
    if exp.keys() not in keys:
        return False
    if {k:v for k, v in exp.items() if k not in ignore_val} not in vals:
        return False

return True
```

Comment: Hi perhaps use sets to compare the keys, and then compare the key-value pairs without the unwanted values?

Comment: Hi, yes but I am trying not having to create a new list/set and complete the check in one loop. I wanted to know if this was achievable i.e. checking for all keys and the limited set of values in one pass like I did using `items()` for all keys and values above.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I understand your main goal, which is to extract the common dictionary in your both lists. So to do that with simple script, I propose you this solution:

```
import json

def set_dict(mydict):
    return set([json.dumps(d) for d in mydict])
```

This simple function is used to transform your list of dictionaries in `set()` object. This is very cool because after that you can do:

```
expected = [{'time': '12:34:22', 'place': 'LA', 'person': 'Mike'}, {'time': '11:45:15', 'place': 'SF', 'person': 'Emily'}] 
actual = [{'time': '12:34:22', 'place': 'LA', 'person': 'Mike'}, {'time': '11:45:15', 'place': 'SF', 'person': 'Emily'}, {'time': '21:19:57', 'place': 'LA', 'person': 'Leo'}, {'time': '15:43:11', 'place': 'LA', 'person': 'Marge'}] 

expected = set_dict(expected)
actual = set_dict(actual)
```

And finally:

```
actual & expected
```

And obtain:

```
{'{"place": "LA", "time": "12:34:22", "person": "Mike"}',
 '{"place": "SF", "time": "11:45:15", "person": "Emily"}'}
```

If you would like the outer sect, you can do:

```
actual - expected
```

To obtain:

```
{'{"place": "LA", "time": "15:43:11", "person": "Marge"}',
 '{"place": "LA", "time": "21:19:57", "person": "Leo"}'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is slightly different.

```
for k, val in expected.iteritems():
    if k not in ignore_values and (k not in act or act[k] != val):
        return False
return True
```